# Retrieval issue in Fusion Charts

Tags: java, mysql, xml, fusioncharts

I am working on FusionCharts.

My requirement is: I need to display stacked3d graph in that when I am generating xml for stacked3d graph, there might be chance for particular month's data won't be available.

XML Format :

```
"<chart palette='2'  bgColor='F0EEEE'    yAxisName='Firewalls Count'  showborder='0'            showPercentInToolTip='0' showLegend='1' showValues='0' labelStep='1' labelDisplay='WRAP'   slantLabels='0' useRoundEdges='1' numDIVLines='4'legendPosition='BOTTOM' legendCaption='Firewalls Onboarding Statistics'>"+
"<categories>"+
"<category label='May-14'/>"+
"<category label='Apr-14'/>"+
"<category label='Mar-14'/>"+
"<category label='Feb-14'/>"+
"<category label='Jan-14'/>"+
"<category label='Dec-13'/>
</categories>"+
"<dataset  seriesName='Firewalls'>"+
 "<set value='14' />"+
 "<set value='9'  />"+
 "<set value='5'  />"+
 "<set value='6'  />"+
 "<set value='14' />"+
 "<set value='9'  />"+
 "</dataset>"+
 "<dataset  seriesName='OS'>"+
 "<set value='2' />"+
 "<set value='3' />"+
 "<set value='7' />"+
 "<set value='5' />"+
 "<set value='2' />"+
 "</dataset>"+
 "<dataset  seriesName='Databases'>"+
 "<set value='6'  />"+
 "<set value='14' />"+
 "<set value='5'  />"+
 "<set value='6'  />"+
 "<set value='14' />"+
 "<set value='9'  />"+
 "</dataset>"+
 "</chart>"
```

In above XML For dataset OS : one set is missing.(one months data is not available in DB)

My condition is if suppose any particular month's record is not there in
database then how can I pass null or 0 value in that.

Please kindly provide your valuable comments.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If database does not contains any value for a particular month, empty set element has to be passed while generating XML data.

Data string should be generated as `<set/>`